# React app rendering problem: Element aspect ratio renders incorrectly in Chrome

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried looking for a solution to this problem, but I cant find it. I'm building a react application and there is a page with some strange zoom on the top when scrolling up or down.
[image: img]

I don't know if this should be a programming question or not because there is nothing unusual on the code, just I can't find the answer and its really driving me crazy. Thanks.

Comment: jsfiddle sample please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was something with my computer. After a big update on macOS, the problem was gone.